# How do I print actual value instead of [[Ljava.lan.Number]?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a sample of numbers. I am storing them in a `List` of data points with timestamps and values. Here is my code:

```
List<Number> samples = {55,67,57,67};
List<Number[]> dps = Lists.newArrayList();

Calender c1; c1.set(2013, 5, 20, 15, 44, 00);

int timeStartSec = (int) (c1.getTime().getTime() / 1000);

for(Number num: samples){
    dps.add(new Number[] { timeStartSec, num});
    timeStartSec = timeStartSec+5;
}

System.out.println("Final DataPoints " + dps);
```

Output:

`Final DataPoints [[Ljava.lang.Number;@af8358, [Ljava.lang.Number;@d80be3, [Ljava.lang.Number;@1f4689e, [Ljava.lang.Number;@1006d75, [Ljava.lang.Number;@1125127, [Ljava.lang.Number;@18dfef8, [Ljava.lang.Number;@15e83f9, [Ljava.lang.Number;@2a5330, [Ljava.lang.Number;@bb7465,]`

Why is it printing as `java.lang.Number` instead of the appropriate value?

Answer (score 9):

Arrays don't override the `toString` method (annoyingly). Have a look at [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).

```
Number[] nums = {1, 2, 3, 4};
System.out.println(nums);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
```

```
[Ljava.lang.Number;@14b7453
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In your case, you will want to call `Arrays.toString` on each element of `dps`, printing / storing the results.

Comment: Interesting nuance about arrays that I wasn't unaware of.

Answer (score 1):

instance of Array does not have the `toString()` method. You may want to use `ArrayList` instead:

```
List<Number> samples - {55,67,57,67};
List<List<Number>> dps = new ArrayList<List<Number>>();

for(Number num: samples){

    dps.add(Arrays.asList(timeStartSec, 10));
    timeStartSec = timeStartSec+5;
}
System.out.println("Final DataPoints " + dps);
```

EDIT: or the static method defined on the class Arrays: [Arrays.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

Comment: Using ArrayList instead of Arrays worked. Thanks

Comment: Changing something fundamental like that (array to list) just for the sake of `toString` seems drastic.

Comment: I don't like combining `Collections` and `Arrays` it is pretty unnatural. I would go either with `Number[][]` or `List<List<Number>>`